# vba: change event code for dropdown missing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdown box in my excel sheet.
At some point vba assigned an event code for the dropdown, which I deleted.

Now I can not use this drop down, because at each value change it complains about 
not being able to execute the deleted code.

If I want to see the code assigen to it throws the error "invalid reference".

How can I delete this event code?

EDIT
The whole error disappears if I add the requested function

```
Public Sub Dropdown4_BeiÄnderung()
' must exist
End Sub
```

But actually I want to be able to delete it.

Comment: What do you mean by "dropdown" was it an ActiveX Combobox, or something else?

Comment: No the excel element Drop down.

Comment: OK. This `Dropown4` shape has been assigned a macro associated with the `BeiÄnderung` event (`OnClick`?).  That is not really important. What you need to do is change the `OnAction` property. This can be done using the method I describe below.

Comment: Is it possible to change this property other then with the code you posted?

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech yes, I think you should be able to right-click on the control, and choose the `Assign Macro`, where you will see it presently `Dropdown4_BeiÄnderung` (or `ThisWorkbookName!Dropdown4_BeiÄnderung`).  Just delete that field so it is empty, and then press `OK`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the `name` of this combobox shape, you could do this in VBA:

```
Sub Dropdown4NoMacro()
Dim shpName as String
shpName = "Drop Down 4" '## Modify as needed.'

ActiveSheet.Shapes(shpName).OnAction = vbNullString
End Sub
```

**Edit** Without VBA:

You should be able to right-click on the control, and choose the `Assign Macro`, where you will see it presently `Dropdown4_BeiÄnderung` (or `ThisWorkbookName!Dropdown4_BeiÄnderung`).

Just delete that field so it is empty, and then press `OK`.  See screenshot, the highlighted field should be empty before press `OK`.

[image: screenshot of Assign Macro dialog]

**Original Answer** (assumed this was connected to the `Worksheet_change` event.

Try pressing ALt+F11 to bring up the Visual Basic Editor. On the left side you should see a list of `Objects` including the Workbook and the several worksheets. Right click on the appropriate worksheet to view the code within that worksheet.

Then, delete any code associated with the `Worksheet_Change` event -- or, post the code here so we can tell you whether there are any portions you might want to keep, while removing *only* the portions impacting the dropdown control.

Comment: The point is that there exists no code, especially nothing like `Worksheet_Change`. The automatic generated code is completely in german, including umlauts...